# StringBuilder substring and reverse - Java

Tags: java

Can anyone help me write me a Java method that takes a substring of a string, reverses it and prints the outcome?

I'm guessing a StringBuilder is better than String but my issue is StringBuilder.substring() returns a String. To continue using StringBuilder I'd need to create a new StringBuilder object to do the StringBuilder.reverse() part.

Anyone a better solution to this?

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("abcdefgh");

    sb = new StringBuilder(sb.subSequence(2, 5));

    sb.reverse(); 
    System.out.println(sb.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this

```
public String reverseString(String normalString) {
   StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
   for(int i = normalString.length() - 1; i >= 0; --i)
     sb.append(normalString.charAt(i));
   return sb.toString();
 }
```

Comment: The latter doesn't work. I'd need to create a new StringBuilder object to then reverse.

Comment: @heyya99 if you got the solution with my answer please accept this as anser

Comment: I think it's overly complicated. I think I could use a String to make it less complicated.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
String s = "Achintya";
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(s.split("")));
Collections.sort(myList, Collections.reverseOrder());
System.out.println(myList);
```

Answer (score 0):

If your desire is to have users input the `start` and `end` indicies of the non-reversed String, you could achieve this easily by re-mapping the index values.

Below is a working example of 1 `StringBuilder` as you asked for:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    final StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("abcdefgh");
    final int startIndex = 2;
    final int endIndex = 5;

    sb.reverse();
    final String output = substring(sb.toString(), startIndex, endIndex);
    System.out.println("Result: " + output);
}

//Retrieve the substring of a reversed string
private static String substring(String input, int start, int end) {
    start = map(start, 0, input.length(), input.length(), 0);
    end = map(end, 0, input.length(), input.length(), 0);

    String substring = input.substring(end, start);
    return substring;
}

//Map value from the min,max range, to the new minRange-maxRange range.
private static int map(float value, float min, float max, float minRange, float maxRange) {
    return Math.round(minRange + (maxRange - minRange) * ((value - min) / (max - min)));
}
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm being marked on this and I need it to be as simple as possible. Your solution's complexity would count against me I fear.

Comment: It is quite simple really, its just calculating the indices in relation to the reverse. The simplest is yours, but instead of the first String builder you just use: `String input = "abcdefgh";`

Answer (score 0):

Your answer is good enough. If you want to use substring method this too will work,

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
StringBuilder revWord = new StringBuilder("abcdefgh".substring(2,5));
revWord.reverse(); 
System.out.println(revWord);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply reverse your operations:

```
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder("abcdefgh");
sb2.reverse();
System.out.println(sb2.subSequence(sb2.length()-5, sb2.length()-2));
```